# PL/SQL Function returns to many values

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I cant understand why my sql function returns the whole table with the same value.

The task is the following:

> Create a PL / SQL CalculationAge (Person) function that returns the difference between the year of death and the year of birth, if the person is already deceased, and the difference between the current year and the year of birth if the person is still alive. The current year should be determined using the DBMS system time.
>   Example: CalculateAlter ('Andrea') should return 24 as the result, and CalculateAlter ('Albert') should return 49."

Im working with the table below.

```
Geboren=birth year
Gestorben=year of dead
Geschlecht=gender
gelebt=lived
```

[I´m working with this table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVuR5.png)

The Code of the function is the following:

```
create or replace FUNCTION BerechneAlter(n_Name varchar)
RETURN Integer 
is
age_result integer;
v_gestorben integer;
v_geboren integer;
Begin
select gestorben, geboren into v_gestorben, v_geboren
from Family
where Family.name = n_Name;
if v_gestorben is Null
then age_result := (2018 - v_geboren);
else 
age_result := v_gestorben - v_geboren;
end if;
return age_result;
end;
```

At the moment the function returns the right value but it shouldn´t do it for every single line of the table.

[result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPFZs.png)

Comment: Hi there Maiwand. If any of the answers given helped you, you should mark it as accepted. To do so chose the one that helped you and answered your question and check the V icon on the left side of it. This will help others with your same doubt to identify how they should proceed or why the problem was happening. Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That`s because you are running it in a context of a query, it is running for every row and calculating just Andrea. In order to return just one result you need to run it just once:

```
select BerechneAlter('Andrea') from dual;
```

And if you want it to calculate for every row in the table you use:

```
select BerechneAlter(name) from family;
```

`dual` is a system table in Oracle to be used to return just one result/value in a query

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer helped me to unterstand my function better, but my function should work in a way, so that it returns the value for the entered parameter(name). For example : " Select BerechneAlter('Andrea') from family; " should return me only the result for Andrea. Is there any way to change my code, so that it works like this?

Comment: No, the way it works is based on the number of rows on your table. When you call a function in a select statement that function will run as many times as there is row on the given table. So if you have a table say "test" and it has 10 rows on it your function would be called 10 times. eg: `select myFunction('someValue') from test` in order to your function run only one time *IN* a select statement is to use the system `dual` table which represents a table with just one row. In other databases only `select myFunction('value')` without `from` would work.

Answer (score 2):

@JorgeCampos already explained why you are getting duplicated output rows.

Let me also suggest that the code of your procedure can be greatly simplified, so the whole logic is executed in the query :

- use NVL to default the date of decease
- use EXTRACT to dynamically compute the current year (instead of hardcoding the value)

Code :

```
create or replace FUNCTION BerechneAlter(n_Name varchar)
RETURN Integer 
IS
    age_result integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT
    NVL(gestorben, EXTRACT(year from sysdate)) - geboren  into age_result
FROM Family
WHERE Family.name = n_Name;

RETURN age_result;
end;
```